# OnClick on inflated items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

In my **activity.xml** I have a `LinearLayout`. This `LinearLayout` contains an inflated layout consisting of four `ImageViews`. Implementation is something like this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_template);
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflated_layout, linearLayout, false);
linearLayout.addView(view);
```

I want to implement an action if the user clicks on the image. However, nothing happens when I click on the image. This is my implementation for onclick event:
`v.getId()` gives me `-1` every time I click an image

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.v("V.getID", String.valueOf(v.getId()));
            Log.v("Image 1 id", String.valueOf(R.id.iv_t_1));

            switch (v.getId()){

                case R.id.iv_t_1: //image 1 clicked
                    //action
                    break;

                case R.id.iv_t_2: //image 2 clicked
                    //action
                    break;

                case R.id.iv_t_3: //image 3 clicked
                    //action
                    break;

                case R.id.iv_t_4: //image 4 clicked
                    //action
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:** The reason i don't want to set listeners on separate images is because the inflated layout is dynamic. It can contain any number from 1 to 4 images. If I have a layout of two images then the fourth imageView listener would return a nullptr exception

Comment: You are setting onClick for your view, not your images view.setOnClickListener

Comment: As @phuc_tran said if you want the click on imageview then you have to set onClick listener to imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find those images and check if it's not null before setting `onClickListener`.

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
if (img1 != null) {
  img1.setOnClickListener(...);
}

ImageView img2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
if (img2 != null) {
  img1.setOnClickListener(...);
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

v.getId() is giving -1 because you have not set any ID to Root Element in the Layout `inflated_layout`. You set an ID to Root Element in "inflated_layout" then `v.getId()` will give you a valid ID.

---

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflated_layout, linearLayout, false);
linearLayout.addView(view);
```

when you add click listener to the view you inflated above, you are adding click listener to the entire layout(inflated_layout) and not to the individual imageviews present inside `inflated_layout`. To add same click listener to all imageviews present inside `inflated_layout` do the following.

Create a private class in the class where you are inflating the `inflated_layout`.

```
 private class ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("test","View Id="+v.getId());
    }

}
```

Then you get a reference to each imageview and set the click listener to each imageview as below.

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_template);
    View view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflated_layout, null);
    linearLayout.addView(view);

    ImageView iv1=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_t_1);
    ImageView iv2=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_t_2);
    ImageView iv3=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_t_3);
    ImageView iv4=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_t_4);

    ClickListener cl=new ClickListener();
    iv1.setOnClickListener(cl);
    iv2.setOnClickListener(cl);
    iv3.setOnClickListener(cl);
    iv4.setOnClickListener(cl);
```

Answer (score 0):

do this,

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.v("V.getID", String.valueOf(v.getId()));
            Log.v("Image 1 id", String.valueOf(R.id.iv_t_1));

            switch (v.getId()){

                case R.id.iv_t_1: //image 1 clicked
                    //action
                    break;

                case R.id.iv_t_2: //image 2 clicked
                    //action
                    break;

                case R.id.iv_t_3: //image 3 clicked
                    //action
                    break;

                case R.id.iv_t_4: //image 4 clicked
                    //action
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```